# What is common practice on assigning top level TFS Scrum Bugs or PBIs to a user? (vs tasks)

Tags: tfs

I have not found much benefit to assigning the top level bug or product backlog item to an individual... since each one has a set of tasks associated with it which are assigned to individuals. Once each task is done I mark the top level item as done.

I'm wondering what the benefit of assigning them to users is?

Comment: Gee, it's too bad someone closed this for some nebulously defined rules violation. I'd have liked to see more discussion on the topic. Thanks for making SO a lesser community, mods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't think of any benefit to the developers having both, however.

**Project Server Integration**

Some people only sync the PBI/UserStory level to Project Server, so assigning these to people can be valuable to project managers using project.

**Owner not Doer**

Something else I've seen is people assigning the PBI to the person in charge of keeping it up to date, or just whoever had the original idea. This way people know who to talk to if there's any questions about the PBI.

Personally I leave them unassigned too.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why this question was closed as it is a problem I am currently facing with TFS but thanks for the answer.

Comment: @JohnHughes i'm not totally sure why it was closed either, seems like a SD question to me, was kinda looking forward to reading other answers